# Failed to establish initial TCP/IP connection (Chilkat-Python)

Tags: python-3.5, raspberry-pi3, chilkat

I'm trying to send a file from **raspberry pi** to my **Windows pc** using **python-chilkat** module. However it is returning this kind of error:

> ChilkatLog: Connect_Ssh: DllDate: Dec 21 2018 ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.76
>   UnlockPrefix: 30-day trial Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
>   Language: armhf linux Python 3.* VerboseLogging: 0 connectInner:
>   hostname: 192.168.1.4   port: 22   sshConnect:
>       connectSocket:
>         connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
>           getsockopt indicates an error.
>           socketErrno: 111
>           socketError: Connection refused
>         --connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
>         connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
>           getsockopt indicates an error.
>           socketErrno: 111
>           socketError: Connection refused
>         --connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
>         connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
>           getsockopt indicates an error.
>           socketErrno: 111
>           socketError: Connection refused
>         --connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
>         connect_ipv6_or_ipv4:
>           getsockopt indicates an error.
>           socketErrno: 111
>           socketError: Connection refused
>         --connect_ipv6_or_ipv4
>       --connectSocket
>       Failed to establish initial TCP/IP connection
>       hostname: 192.168.1.4
>       port: 22   --sshConnect
>   --connectInner  Failed.
>   --Connect_Ssh
>   --ChilkatLog

Can someone explain to me why Im getting these error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this online example which experiments with different failure cases to see what errors are returned:   https://www.example-code.com/chilkat2-python/socket_connect_fail.asp

In some of the test cases, you'll see "connection rejected" which is the same as "connection refused".  In other cases you'll get a timeout.  The cases that result in "connection rejected" are the most likely causes for the failure.

PS> I understand that the example I'm pointing to is for a simple TCP socket connection, but SSH begins with a simple TCP connection, and that is what is failing.